# comboboxes userforms Based on list selection to other worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Based on the selection made in a combo box on a userform how do I send the selection made to a desired worksheet. For example, we have 12 worksheets in a work book. Each worksheets name is a name of a month in the year. The combo box selection is all the months of the year. January - December. I f I select January in the combo box I want all the other entries on the userform to go to January worksheet. If I select February I want all the entries in the other text boxes to go to February worksheet and so on. How do I accomplish this?? Any help will be greatly appriciated!!!

I re-edited the code. Only problem now is the cellVal4 = Me.tbDate.Text The error lies with the .Text highlighted. Also when I submit the form it does not add a new row for each entry it changes the same row the first entry was on.

```
            Option Explicit
```

Dim WrkSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim ssheet As Workbook
Dim cellVal1 As String, cellVal2 As String, cellVal3 As String, cellVal4 As String, cellVal5 As String, cellVal6 As String, cellVal7 As String, cellVal8 As String, cellVal9 As String, cellVal10 As String, cellVal11 As String, cellVal12 As String
Dim cellVal13 As String, cellVal14 As String, cellVal15 As String, cellVal16 As String, cellVal17 As String, cellVal18 As String, cellVal19 As String, cellVal20 As String, cellVal21 As String, cellVal22 As String
Dim cellVal23 As String, cellVal24 As String, cellVal25 As String, cellVal26 As String, cellVal27 As String, cellVal28 As String, cellVal29 As String, cellVal30 As String, cellVal31 As String, cellVal32 As String, cellVal33 As String, cellVal34 As String

```
Dim shtCmb As String
Dim RwLast As Long

shtCmb = Me.cmbListItem1.Value
If shtCmb = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please choose a month.", vbOKOnly
    Me.cmbListItem1.SetFocus
End If

cellVal1 = Me.cmbListItem1.Text
cellVal2 = Me.cmbListItem2.Text
cellVal3 = Me.cmbListItem3.Text
cellVal4 = Me.TextBox31.Text
cellVal5 = Me.TextBox1.Text
cellVal6 = Me.TextBox2.Text
cellVal7 = Me.TextBox3.Text
cellVal8 = Me.TextBox4.Text
cellVal9 = Me.TextBox5.Text
cellVal10 = Me.TextBox6.Text
cellVal11 = Me.TextBox7.Text
cellVal12 = Me.TextBox8.Text
cellVal13 = Me.TextBox9.Text
cellVal14 = Me.TextBox10.Text
cellVal15 = Me.TextBox11.Text
cellVal16 = Me.TextBox12.Text
cellVal17 = Me.TextBox13.Text
cellVal18 = Me.TextBox14.Text
cellVal19 = Me.TextBox15.Text
cellVal20 = Me.TextBox16.Text
cellVal21 = Me.TextBox17.Text
cellVal22 = Me.TextBox18.Text
cellVal23 = Me.TextBox19.Text
cellVal24 = Me.TextBox20.Text
cellVal25 = Me.TextBox21.Text
cellVal26 = Me.TextBox22.Text
cellVal27 = Me.TextBox23.Text
cellVal28 = Me.TextBox24.Text
cellVal29 = Me.TextBox25.Text
cellVal30 = Me.TextBox26.Text
cellVal31 = Me.TextBox27.Text
cellVal32 = Me.TextBox28.Text
cellVal33 = Me.TextBox29.Text
cellVal34 = Me.TextBox30.Text

RwLast = Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & Worksheets(shtCmb).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal1
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AJ" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal2
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("A" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal3
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AH" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal4
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("B" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal5
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("C" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal6
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("D" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal7
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("E" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal8
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("F" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal9
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("G" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal10
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("H" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal11
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("I" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal12
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("J" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal13
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("K" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal14
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("L" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal15
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("M" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal16
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("N" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal17
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("O" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal18
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("P" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal19
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("Q" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal20
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("R" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal21
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("S" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal22
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("T" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal23
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("U" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal24
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("V" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal25
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("W" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal26
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("X" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal27
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("Y" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal28
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("Z" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal29
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AA" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal30
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AB" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal31
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AC" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal32
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AD" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal33
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AF" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal34

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub cmbListItem1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub optionCancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim Entry As Variant

    ' MonthName(Month(Now)) - Will return the name of the current Month
    For Each SH In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If SH.Name = MonthName(month(Now)) Then
            Set WrkSheet = SH
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem1
        For Each Entry In [List1]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
        .Value = MonthName(month(Now))
    End With
    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem2
        For Each Entry In [List2]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With
    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem3
        For Each Entry In [List3]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: In order for us to help you with this issue, we need you to post some of the code you've tried, or the research into some VBA code that will fulfill this function. Stack Overflow is designed to be a Q & A help site for programming questions, but the way your question is currently worded it will look to many users as if you are asking us to write your code for you. (which in turn will lead them to ignore this question)

Comment: It is to long to enter it all.

Comment: Private Sub cmbListItem1_Change()
If Me.cmbListItem1.Value = "January" Then
    Worksheets("January").Range("AI2").Value = Me.cmbListItem1.Text
End If
If Me.cmbListItem1.Value = "February" Then
    Worksheets("February").Range("AI2").Value = Me.cmbListItem1.Text
End If
If Me.cmbListItem1.Value = "March" Then
    Worksheets("March").Range("AI2").Value = Me.cmbListItem1.Text
End If

Comment: You should be able to edit it into your original post. I'm assuming you pasted what you could into the comments, so I'll take a stab at what you're working with, but a fully copy of the code in your question (with ` marks around it) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, this will work. I have a question, however. It looks like you want it to enter in the data on the next empty row on each sheet so you don't overwrite your data, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first combobox will only have the names of your sheets, you could use this instead to shorten your code significantly:

```
Private Sub cmbListItem1_Change()

Dim cellVal as String
Dim shtCmb As String
shtCmb = Me.cmbListItem1.Value
cellVal = Me.cmbListItem1.Text

If shtCmb = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please choose a month.", vbOKOnly
    Me.cmbListItem1.SetFocus
End If

Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI2").Value = cellVal    
End Sub
```

For each of your combobox inputs, you can just change the output variable for the cell's value.

```
Private Sub cmbListItem2_Change()

Dim cellVal as String
Dim shtCmb As String
shtCmb = Me.cmbListItem1.Value
cellVal = Me.cmbListItem2.Text

If shtCmb = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please choose a month.", vbOKOnly
    Me.cmbListItem1.SetFocus
End If

Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AJ2").Value = cellVal
End Sub
```

However, this code should change the values of the cells in those sheets every time a change is made. If that's what you want, this should do it. If you want it to input all of the values when you click an enter button, I can help with that too.

EDIT:

I've changed the code to update the cells on your accept button click event (what I'm assuming to be an accept button anyways) and update the next empty cells below whatever is already in there. This code assumes that some values are already in row 1, most likely headers. Give this a shot on a copy of your workbook, not the actual one, and it should work. I am unable to test this as I don't have a copy of your working data.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Dim ssheet As Workbook
Dim cellVal1 As String, cellVal2 As String, cellVal3 As String, cellVal4 As String, cellVal5 As String
Dim cellVal6 As String, cellVal7 As String
Dim shtCmb As String
Dim RwLast As Long
shtCmb = Me.cmbListItem1.Value

If shtCmb = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please choose a month.", vbOKOnly
    Me.cmbListItem1.SetFocus
End If

cellVal1 = Me.cmbListItem1.Text
cellVal2 = Me.cmbListItem2.Text
cellVal3 = Me.cmbListItem3.Text
cellVal4 = Me.tbDate.Text
cellVal5 = Me.TextBox1.Text
cellVal6 = Me.TextBox2.Text
cellVal7 = Me.TextBox3.Text

RwLast = Range("AI" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal1
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AJ" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal2
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("A" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal3
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AH" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal4
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("B" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal5
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("C" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal6
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("D" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal7

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.tbDate = Date


'fill the combo box
For Each entry In [List1]
    Me.cmbListItem1.AddItem entry
Next entry

'fill the combo box
For Each entry In [List2]
    Me.cmbListItem2.AddItem entry

Next entry

'fill the combo box
For Each entry In [List3]
    Me.cmbListItem3.AddItem entry

Next entry



End Sub
```

Note that this is a very clumsy way of completing this code on my part, I know there should be a better way to iterate between your ranges and entry values, but as I am not a master this is the simplest way to complete the code.

Comment: So far I think most of it works. I am getting a run time error '91': Object variable or With Block variable not set. I believe that is on the submit button. That is what I am having the tough time with. I was trying to get it to add new entry to different rows. Any ideas on the submit button and a fuctionality for it? Thanks.–  Gary Carroll16 hours ago

Comment: I'll be revising my code for that soon. An important note, however: you shouldn't be trying to edit my answer to your question as a response to our conversation. You can edit your question to include what you are discussing, however.

Comment: Thanks for the advise and all your help. I am really just learning VBA. I can do Javascript pretty well but VBA is just a little different. Just that lanuage barrier. LOL. Thanks again.

Comment: Can I send you my spreedsheet or attach it some how? It is still having trouble working.

Comment: Can I send you my spreedsheet or attach it some how? It is still having trouble working. Information goes into the right sheet but it takes me directly to an error. Compile error Variable not defined RWLast=

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I forgot to declare the variable for that. try this iteration of the code, it should be declaring properly.

Comment: Okay I think we are there only one error is coming up. Compile error: Method or Data member not found. cellVal14 + Me.tbDate.Text  The .Text is highlighted.

Comment: Only other issue I see is it is only changining the values in the same cells and not entering the data as a new row each time.

Comment: I re-posted the edited code. Please see my comments above. Thanks!!

Comment: Okay. Here is the error I am getting. Run-Time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error. The error points to Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & RwLast + 1). Value=cellCal1   Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I have fixed the other date code. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Here is the error I am getting. Run-Time error '1004' Methode range of object Global failed. The error points to Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & RwLast + 1). Value=cellCal1 Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I have fixed the other date code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the below within your UserForm Code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim WrkSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim SH As Worksheet
For Each SH In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If SH.Name = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
        Set WrkSheet = SH
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Then in the rest of your UserForm code you should be able to reference the correct sheet by: Example

```
MsgBox WrkSheet.Range("A1").Value
```

EDIT: Added code

```
Option Explicit
Dim WrkSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
    Dim SSheet As Workbook
    Dim NR As Long

    NR = SSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Row + 1
    'Not sure what you are trying to do below ???
    SSheet.Cells(NR, 1) = "???"
End Sub

Private Sub cmbListItem1_Change()
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    For Each SH In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If SH.Name = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
            Set WrkSheet = SH
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    WrkSheet.Range("AI2").Value = Me.cmbListItem1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub cmbListItem2_Change()
    WrkSheet.Range("AJ2").Value = Me.cmbListItem2.Text
End Sub

Private Sub cmbListItem3_Change()
    WrkSheet.Range("A2").Value = Me.cmbListItem3.Text
End Sub

Private Sub tbDate_Click()
    WrkSheet.Range("AH2").Value = Me.tbDate.Text
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    WrkSheet.Range("B2").Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    WrkSheet.Range("C2").Value = Me.TextBox2.Text
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    WrkSheet.Range("D2").Value = Me.TextBox3.Text
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim Entry As Variant

    ' MonthName(Month(Now)) - Will return the name of the current Month
    For Each SH In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If SH.Name = MonthName(Month(Now)) Then
            Set WrkSheet = SH
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Me.tbDate = Date
    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem1
        For Each Entry In [List1]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
        .Value = MonthName(Month(Now))
    End With
    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem2
        For Each Entry In [List2]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With
    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem3
        For Each Entry In [List3]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With
End Sub
```

The above is untested, but give it a try and see if it helps resolve your issue.

EDIT:  Added another code variation Below:
The Below will add all UserForm Values to the Sheet with the Month Name Selected in the List.  I kept the original Columns used in your example.

```
Option Explicit
Dim WrkSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
    Dim NR As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With WrkSheet
        NR = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
            'If there is a specific column (Example: A) you can use
            'NR = .Range("A" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("AI" & NR).Value = Me.cmbListItem1.Text
        .Range("AJ" & NR).Value = Me.cmbListItem2.Text
        .Range("A" & NR).Value = Me.cmbListItem3.Text
        .Range("AH" & NR).Value = Me.tbDate.Text
        .Range("B" & NR).Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
        .Range("C" & NR).Value = Me.TextBox2.Text
        .Range("D" & NR).Value = Me.TextBox3.Text
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmbListItem1_Change()
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    For Each SH In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If SH.Name = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
            Set WrkSheet = SH
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim Entry As Variant
    Set WrkSheet = Sheet3 ' You can Change or Remove This if you choose
    ' MonthName(Month(Now)) - Will return the name of the current Month
    For Each SH In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If SH.Name = MonthName(Month(Now)) Then
            Set WrkSheet = SH
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Me.tbDate = Date
    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem1
        For Each Entry In [List1]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
        .Value = MonthName(Month(Now))
    End With
    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem2
        For Each Entry In [List2]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With
    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem3
        For Each Entry In [List3]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do I put this in the submit button? That way it will submit to the worksheet that I need it to. Also here is just a small piece of code. I have put this type of code in all 34 of my textboxes.      Private Sub cmbListItem1_Change()
If Me.cmbListItem1.Value = "January" Then
    Worksheets("January").Range("AI2").Value = Me.cmbListItem1.Text
End If

Comment: I have reedited the original and added the sample code. Thanks.

Comment: So far I think most of it works. I am getting a run time error '91': Object variable or With Block variable not set. I believe that is on the submit button. That is what I am having the tough time with. I was trying to get it to add new entry to different rows. Any ideas on the submit button and a fuctionality for it? Thanks.

Comment: I am getting a compile error Wrong number or arguments or invalid property assignment. The line that fives the error is Private sub btnSubmit_Click() and then the 3rd line of code ThisWorkbook.Sheets. Sheets is highlighted.

Comment: Okay when you select a month from the combobox then all the data on the form should be submited to the particular worksheet i.e. if you select January on the combobox it will submit all the data on the form to the january worksheet if february was selected it would go to the february worksheet. This will need to create a new entry each time. There could be numerous entries on the worksheet that the data is going into. This is all done through a user form.

Comment: Imagine a woorkbook that has 14 sheets. First sheet is where the userform will open and have instructions on how to use the userform. sheet2 is where the lists are stored for the combobox, this sheet is hidden. Sheet 3-15 are the name of the month. Sheet 3 is January sheet 4 February. The columns of each sheet go froom A-AJ. You are the user. You fill the form out and select January for the month when you hit the submit button the data on the form goes into the sheet "January" Lets say you have another entry for January this entry should populate to the next line. This is what I am trying todo

Comment: @GaryCarroll - I added some additional code to the bottom of my post.  Take a look and see if its closer to what you need.

Comment: I just fixed the rest of the code and this works perfect. Thanks for your help!!